# What is a metric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having a bit of trouble finding a source of study to metric matrices (I'm not even sure whether this is how we call them in English). It is introduced along with vector inner products. I can't find anything on them in Portuguese, and I've had no luck with English either.

I have the following exercise:

Consider an oriented euclidean vector space V and its direct (what is direct?) base $B=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$, whose vectors are such that:

$||v_1|| = 2√2$,
$||v_2||=2$,
$||v_3||=1$
$∡(v_1,v_2) = π/2; ∡(v_1,v_3) = π/4; ∡(v_2,v_3) = π/3$

I have no idea what to do with the angles. Should I use the inner product formula?

Then, the exercise is: Prove the metric matrix of V in respect to the basis B is

$$\pmatrix{8 &0 &2\\0 &4& 1\\ 2& 1 &1}$$

It would be of great help if someone could tell me where to find more info on this. I'm not sure the correct terminology is "metric matrices", but that's the only translation I can come up with from Portuguese.

Thanks in advance!
￼￼￼￼

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just going to use a dot for the inner product. The matrix you want is symmetric positive definite, let us call it $M.$  The rule is
$$  m_{ij} = v_i \cdot v_j $$
This is often called the Gram matrix. However, sometimes half of this is called the Gram matrix, so you need some context usually.

Probably worth this note: often enough, the Gram matrix is taken as half the Hessian matrix of a given quadratic form. So, given the familiar form $x^2 + y^2 + z^2,$ the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives is $2I.$ Many people would take the Gram matrix as $I,$ many others would use $2I.$ Caution is required. Oh: if you are given the Hessian matrix $H,$ the form (metric) applied to a column vector $x$ is $(1/2) x^T H x.$

Details: note
$$ v_i \cdot v_i = \|v_i \|^2 $$
The Law of Cosines says 
$$ v_i \cdot v_j = \|v_i \|  \|v_j \| \cos \theta. $$

Compare a different basis, for a root lattice called $D_3,$ at http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/D3.html  which specifies the Gram matrix. On this website, the basis vectors are the rows under BASIS, and the GRAM matrix is as I said, not divided by 2 at all.

Meanwhile, if someone specifies a basis for you as rows of a matrix, call that $R,$ from Nebe
$$
R = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
we get Gram matrix $G = R R^T,$ in $D_3$
$$
G = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Gram matrix! Yes, that's it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Given the base $B = (v_1,v_2,v_3)$, the "metric matrix" of $V$ with respect to $B$ is
$$
\newcommand{\<}{\langle}
\newcommand{\>}{\rangle}
M = 
\pmatrix{\<v_1,v_1\> & \<v_1,v_2\> & \< v_1,v_3 \>\\
\<v_2,v_1\> & \<v_2,v_2\> & \< v_2,v_3 \>\\
\<v_3,v_1\> & \<v_3,v_2\> & \< v_3,v_3 \>}
$$ 
You can figure out what these entries are using the inner product formula.

Answer (score 0):

Metric Matrix is also called a Metric Tensor. 
Unlike the variable change theorem which requires differentiability. Metric Tensor change could be made on any integrable function via tangent vectors.
On WikiPedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the input. I had come across that link previously, but I wasn't sure whether or not that is what I'm looking for. And where exactly can I fit that particular exercise? Thanks, once again.

Comment: And isn't there any way to get a grasp of what exactly this is without delving in Differential Geometry? This is a Linear Algebra course and I'm not sure the professor would introduce these concepts without having Differential Geometry first.

Comment: There is no need to go into Differential Geometry. Try looking for an advanced Calculus course. Have a look HERE: http://math.huji.ac.il/~mbartzi/teaching/advanced_calculus.html, weeks 10-14 should cover most of it. It's a 2nd year course, when Differential Geometry is usually learned in masters degree.